# How to hide subplot labels in facet graph?

Tags: altair

This code:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

alt.Chart(data.iris()).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalLength:Q',
    y='petalWidth:Q',
    facet=alt.Facet('species:N', header=alt.Header(labels=False, title=None), columns=3)
).properties(
    width=250,
    height=250
)
```

produces this chart:

[image: chart]

I have added red lines beneath what I [believe](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2252) are called subplot "labels". How can I remove them? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51549474/name-or-title-facets) asked how to change them, and @jakevdp said that is impossible. [This question](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2252) asked how to remove them (same as me), and @jakevdp hasn't answered yet. They used a `column` parameter to eliminate the labels, but when I try that, it complains about the `columns` parameter I'm using. I want to both (a) eliminate the labels and (b) limit the number of subplots per row, with automatic row wrapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did should have worked (i.e. `alt.Header(title=None, labels=False)`); the fact that it doesn't is probably a bug (I think it's the same issue reported here: https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2252)

As a workaround for the issue, you can use `labelExpr` to hide them:

```json
alt.Chart(data.iris()).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalLength:Q',
    y='petalWidth:Q',
    facet=alt.Facet('species:N', header=alt.Header(labelExpr="''", title=None), columns=3)
).properties(
    width=250,
    height=250
)
```